# R Dplyr Extracting Estimates from Linear Model and use them for Variable Adjustment Mutattions - for Multiple Columns

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr

## ***Problem***

I am working on a study that is using data from food diaries. I need to adjust the nutrients for total energy intake. I will make the adjustment with the nutrient residual model described by [Willet et al. 1997](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/65/4/1220S/4655744).
In order to calculate this residual, I need to go through a few steps to mutate the nutrient columns, that involve extracting estimates from linear models. I want to do this with dplyr if possible, but I don't know how to do that exactly.

---

## ***Example***

Here is an sample of my data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  energy = c(3582, 3703, 3810, 3909, 4047, 4311, 4476, 4714, 5000, 5053, 5113, 5350, 5585, 5757, 6235, 6625, 6692, 6827, 6884, 7047, 7174, 7311, 7573, 7968, 10797, 11070),
  protein = c(43.55, 45.2, 48.1, 49.1, 54.6, 56.4, 61.15, 65.55, 70, 70.7, 71.55, 71.65, 74.15, 77.55, 79.2, 80.6, 81.6, 83.15, 83.2, 85.85, 91.85, 92.5, 98.4, 101.65, 105.6, 146.3),
  fat = c(20.9, 21.95, 25.7, 25.95, 34.95, 37.3, 38.2, 39.45, 40.8, 44.55, 44.95, 45.1, 48, 48.4, 52.3, 59.6, 62.15, 63.7, 64.1, 64.45, 67.5, 67.55, 70.95, 73.7, 88.6, 111.2))
```

From a linear regression model with protein as the dependent variable and energy as the independent variable, I extract the intercept and slope:

```
lm(protein ~ energy, data=df) #intercept = 10.56574 slope = 0.01095
```

I need to use these estimates to mutate the nutrient variable (protein) to get the adjusted nutrient variable (adjusted_protein):

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(protein_residual = protein - (10.56574+0.01095 *energy),
         expected_protein_from_mean_kj = (10.56574+0.01095*mean(energy)),
         adjusted_protein = protein_residual+expected_protein_from_mean_kj)
```

or simplified since I need the to adjust the nutrient directly :

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(protein = (protein - (10.56574+0.01095 *energy)) + (10.56574+0.01095*mean(energy)))
```

---

## ***Goal***

Since I have more than one nutrient variable that I need to adjust for energy intake, I would like to run the simplified mutation on multiple columns at once. I tried defining a custom function and placing it in my call to mutate_at, but I got an error message:

```
residual <- function(data, nutrient, energy){
    (nutrient - (lm(nutrient ~ energy, data=data)$coefficient[1] + lm(nutrient ~ energy, data=data)$coefficient[2] * energy)) + 
    (lm(nutrient ~ energy, data=data)$coefficient[1] + lm(nutrient ~ energy, data=data)$coefficient[2] * mean(energy)) 
}

df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(protein,fat), funs(residual(.,energy)))

# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: numeric 'envir' arg not of length one.
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `residual()` function has three arguments, but you don't actually need the `data` argument.  In `lm()`, the `data` argument is only required if `x` and `y` are column names, but in this case they contain the entire vectors needed to compute the regression.

Just reduce the arguments list of `residual()` to `residual(nutrient, energy)`, and remove the `data` arguments from the `lm()` calls in `residual()`, and your function will execute without error.

With:

```
residual <- function(nutrient, energy){
    mod <- lm(nutrient ~ energy)
    (nutrient - (mod$coefficient[1] + mod$coefficient[2] * energy)) + 
    (mod$coefficient[1] + mod$coefficient[2] * mean(energy)) 
}
```

Then:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(protein, fat), funs(residual(., energy)))
   energy  protein      fat
1    3582 70.27792 46.73896
2    3703 70.60333 46.50843
3    3810 72.33200 49.12606
4    3909 72.24825 48.32835
5    4047 76.23757 55.86791
...
```

Comment: I see that I wrote "data = df" in my code. That was a mistake, since my data frames wont actually be called df, and won't be called the same thing either, so i need a function that can take the different data frame names into account. I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Ok good to know. But either way, the issue is the same, you were missing an argument. I'm afk now, can update later - but feel free to edit my answer if you can solve yourself with this answer as a starting point!

Comment: I'll see if I can manage, otherwise I'll wait for you, or someone else, to answer.

Comment: Now while keeping the three arguments, my function will work in my call to mutate_at, as long as I add arguments to my call like so: 
`funs(residual(data_frame, ., energy))`
Is there a way to replace `data_frame` to something that reflects the data frame used in the previous step of the pipe chain? "." reflects the selected vars, so that won't work.

Comment: IIUC, you still don't need `data` as an argument to `residual()`, because you don't actually need to specify `data` as an argument in `lm()` in this case.  See my updated solution and explanation - does that work?